# How to Loop through InfiniSpan Cache entries

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, spring-cache

i am using infinispan cache and have to loop through all the entries in a cache and find out cache keys and values. i've found that it can be done through entrySet using below approach

```
cache.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

but it looks like the class implementing cache functionality doesn't support `entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()` methods

below is the screenshot of the code in debug mode, it looks like the instance `nativeCache` is of class `org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache` which has a private inner class `EntryWrapper` which has methods to `getKey` and `getValue` , but since it's a private class, i can't access it.

[image]

[image]

is there a way for me to getKeys and Values of all the entries in a cache?

Comment: What exception are you getting? The Infinispan cache extends the `Map` interface and `entrySet()` returns a set of `Map.Entry` which have access to `getKey()` and `getValue()`. Also, I tried `cache.getNativeCache().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", key, value));` and it works fine for me

Comment: @pruivo `cache.getNativeCache().forEach(key, value)` worked for me. can you explain which interface has this method `(key,value)` that you provided anonymous implementation for. also please put your comment as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Infinispan Cache interface extends Java's [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) interface. You can use any of the methods available to iterate over the Cache content.

The `forEach()` method accepts a `BiConsumer`.